# GWT - How to check session in a datasourceservlet?

Tags: session, gwt, datasource, visualization, google-visualization

I have a visualization DataSourceServlet in a GWT application, which is used to generate a data table and return data table to visualization api.
The datasourceservlet can only be accessed by a authenticated user.

I am using getThreadLocalRequest to check for session in other RemoteServiceServlet, but it is not available for DatasourceServlet.

How can i check if the user has a valid session in DatasourceServlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the javadoc below, DataSourceServlet exposes doGet and doPost methods which contain HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse as parameters.

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/dev/dsl_javadocs/com/google/visualization/datasource/DataSourceServlet.html

You would get the session object from the request parameter like it is done for servlets in general. request.getSession()